# mongoDB servers are not available when the master is down

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

Once I turn off the master node, the other nodes are down, too.

I can **NOT** get data from other nodes (if the master is down/off )

The following errors happends when the master replica is down

```
ConnectionPool::PoolShuttingDownError (ConnectionPool::PoolShuttingDownError):
Moped::Errors::ConnectionFailure (Could not connect to a primary node for replica set #<Moped::Cluster:70117691586500 @seeds=[<Moped::Node resolved_address="0.0.0.0:27017">]>
```

I have 3 mongoDB replicas.

It seems the primary replica is  **172.19.16.109:27017**

I don't understand why I shutdown the machine **172.19.16.109**,

And remaining 2 replicas are unavailable to load data from its database.

Is it not making sense for the replicas ? Once if the master is shutdown, the others are also unavailable, too.

I expect that even if any replica is  down, the others should work correctly.

My configurations are as below.

```
vvtk_dqa:PRIMARY> rs.conf()
{
    "_id" : "vvtk_dqa",
    "version" : 4,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "host" : "172.19.16.109:27017"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "host" : "172.19.16.104:27017"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 3,
            "host" : "192.168.14.7:27017"
        }
    ]
}
```

## mongodb.conf

```
# Where to store the data.
dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb

#where to log
logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log

logappend=true

bind_ip = 0.0.0.0
#port = 27017

# Enable journaling, http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Journaling
journal=true

replSet=vvtk_dqa
```

### isMaster

```
vvtk_dqa:PRIMARY> rs.isMaster()
{
    "setName" : "vvtk_dqa",
    "setVersion" : 4,
    "ismaster" : true,
    "secondary" : false,
    "hosts" : [
        "172.19.16.109:27017",
        "192.168.14.7:27017",
        "172.19.16.104:27017"
    ],
    "primary" : "172.19.16.109:27017",
    "me" : "172.19.16.109:27017",
    "maxBsonObjectSize" : 16777216,
    "maxMessageSizeBytes" : 48000000,
    "maxWriteBatchSize" : 1000,
    "localTime" : ISODate("2015-02-11T02:05:12.021Z"),
    "maxWireVersion" : 2,
    "minWireVersion" : 0,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

After I shutdown the 172.19.16.109, and type `rs.status()` on `192.168.14.7`

and still can not get any data from `192.168.14.7` or `172.19.16.104`

```
vvtk_dxa:PRIMARY> rs.status()
{
    "set" : "vvtk_dqa",
    "date" : ISODate("2015-02-12T01:51:37Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "172.19.16.109:27017",
            "health" : 0,
            "state" : 8,
            "stateStr" : "(not reachable/healthy)",
            "uptime" : 0,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1423649845, 1),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-02-11T10:17:25Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2015-02-12T01:51:28Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2015-02-11T10:31:04Z"),
            "pingMs" : 0,
            "syncingTo" : "192.168.14.7:27017"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "name" : "172.19.16.104:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 4,
            "stateStr" : "FATAL",
            "uptime" : 64832,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1423545748, 1),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-02-10T05:22:28Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2015-02-12T01:51:37Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2015-02-12T01:51:35Z"),
            "pingMs" : 0
        },
        {
            "_id" : 3,
            "name" : "192.168.14.7:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 64835,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1423704914, 1),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-02-12T01:35:14Z"),
            "self" : true
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: I don't exactly understand the problem. It looks like you have a primary. Was that error message temporary? It takes a few seconds for a new primary to be elected when the previous primary goes down. Can you give us examples of operations that you expect to work but aren't working, and what the context is where they don't work? Please include the full error messages.

Comment: Once I turn off the master, the other cluster can not be connected in. I can not get data from other clusters

Comment: You can't get data from the other set members because they appear to be down or suffering from a fatal error. I can't help you further without more information.

Comment: @wdberkeley hi it seems the distributed DB not making sense as I think, if I want to have high availlity even if some members are down, what should I do?

Comment: Get your set in a healthy state. With 3 members, your replica set is healthy even if one member goes down. Right now, from the point of view of the primary, 2 members are in an unhealthy state. You need to address the problems with those two members. Perhaps you should read the [intro to replication](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication-introduction/)?